# Importing Dictionary Fails

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get too clever for my own good and have split out the data in my python script into three files. I want to bring the two reference files dictionaries into the main script, but can't get them to load no matter what I do. I'm sure its something simple, but I'm at my wits end. All the files are in the same folder.

Swordguy.py

```
stats = {
"Name":"Swordguy",
"Hp":20,
"Mp":20,
"St":20,
"Fight":8,
"Magic":2,
"Sneak":4,
"Athletics":2,
"Animal":0,
"Traps":-2
}
```

Room.py

```
info = {
    "Name": "Rat Warren",
    "Fight": 0,
    "Magic": 2,
    "Sneak": -2,
    "Athletics": 0,
    "Animal": 2
}
```

Testing.py

```
from Swordguy import stats
from Room import info
charname = stats["Name"]
roomname = info["Name"]
print(stats["Name"]+" arrives in the room "+info["Name"])
```

End result should read `Swordguy arrived in the room Rat Warren` but I'm getting the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'stats' from 'Swordguy'
```

I'm running the code in Visual Studio Core. I'm just using the inbuilt run command shift+enter

Edit 2: Looks like something is going on in how I'm running the code. Thanks everyone, glad its not just me losing my marbles.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If it is Spyder or Canopy, try restarting the kernel with `ctrl` + `.` and then trying

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Are you sure the variable is named `stats`? I get that error if the variable name doesn't match the import

Comment: did you try run that code in terminal, without VSC?
your code works for me exactly as you wanted

Comment: I seem to remember seeing something like this before, and it turned out to be a misunderstanding of VSCode. I think Shift+Enter is "Run selected code", right? There should be another shortcut to run the whole file.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a function in Swordguy.py like this

```
def get_stats():
    return stats
```

And do the same for Room.py

Now in testing.py import that function and call it like

```
from Swordguy import get_stats
from Room import get_info
stats = get_stats()
info = get_info()
charname = stats["Name"]
roomname = info["Name"]
```

Comment: No, this is not needed